# Setting Vim Options with Variables

Tags: vim, set, let

I've a question that should be fairly simple, but I have yet to find a solution for.  I'm editing my .vimrc and would like to set an option using results saved in a variable.  For example, I would like to aggregate all my temporary files in ~/.vimetc.  Here's what I would like to do,

```
let s:vimetc=$HOME.'/vimetc/'
set backupdir=s:vimetc.'backups/'
set directory=s:vimetc.'vimswap/'
set viewdir=s:vimetc.'vimswap/'
```

Of course, set doesn't resolve variables so I just end up with the literal |s:vimetc.'backups/'|, not at all what I would like.  I tried using &s:vimetc with similar results.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
let &backupdir=s:vimetc.'backups/'
```

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:let-option